# Clickable image with z-index: -1

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I think this is pretty simple but can't figure out why I can't click my image.

So I have a main `div` and inside it I have an image with `position:absolute;` to place it a little bit outside the `main-div`.

The problem is that I have an `anchor` on my image and it's not clickable for some reason.

I've tried to give `img`and `div` both positive `z-index` but still not working.

Basically I want the image clickable.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/90ob5p85/)

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container main-div">
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.mon-wallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/Ourson.jpg" class="bear"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-div{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 200px;;
    width:400px;
    background:white;
    border:6px solid #c8c8c8;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
}
.bear{
    z-index: -1;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-70px;
}

body{background-color:white;}
```

Comment: why are you trying to put image behind everything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit strange solution, but you can set `z-index: -2` to body. Now, the body has `z-index: 0` and link/image `-1`.

```
body{position: relative; z-index: -2}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/90ob5p85/1/

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the body. And yes, its a strange solution but the only one I came up with.

Comment: @azhpo: another is to change html markup, id don't know if it's your real html or just a code snippet showing the problem. But lower negative z-index will work correctly.

Comment: It's not my real code, because my real code is much more. It was just an example showing my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest an alternative to your HTML structure? In my opinion .bear shouldn't be contained within .main-div, as it is visually not contained within the container.

You can get the desired result by restructuring the HTML like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-div">
    <!-- Some other stuff -->
    </div>
    <div class="shybear">
        <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.mon-wallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/Ourson.jpg" class="bear"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-div{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 200px;;
    width:400px;
    background:white;
    border:6px solid #c8c8c8;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 200px;
    width:400px;
}
.shybear {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
}
.bear{
    z-index: -1;
    width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/90ob5p85/3/

Sorry for changing the class names (and coming up with stupid names). You should give the classes appropriate names.

Answer (score -1):

How about to use `opacity` attribute like `.bear {opacitiy: 0;}`?

http://jsfiddle.net/90ob5p85/2/

Comment: What?! Why would I give `opacity:0` ?